# Accessing HTTP request platform

Tags: linux, http, post, request

On an Internet browser, do you know which keys to press or software to install to access the http request platform for POST? Does the HTTP request connect well with LINUX system?

Comment: What do you mean with: 'access the http request platform for POST'?

Comment: like accessing the text screen to write http POST request

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about **Developer Tools**, you can access them for example by pressing `F12` key or `Ctrl + Shift + I` or in OSX `Cmd + Option + i`.

Requests can be found in **Network Tab** (at least for Chrome and Firefox).

In this tab in Firefox you can right-click on your request and choose "Edit and resend".

If you prefer command line tools, on Linux you can also use many more tools, e.g. [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/form.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser You may want to install plug-ins that allow You to hand-craft diverse requests, send those request and let You look at the responses.

Look at Your browsers plug-in repo and search for "REST".